# MongoDB - find match criteria in database

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Is it possible to find the match criteria in a database?
Request 1 looks up the criterion in the database, request 2 uses the criterion to match and returns another projection. Can this be handled in a request?

```
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15 * time.Second)
defer cancel()
cursor, err := clients.MongoClient.Database("somedb").Collection("collection").
    Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{
        bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{
            {"field", crit1},
            {"field2", crit2},
        }}},
        bson.D{
            {"$lookup", bson.M{ // Not sure if this is usefull. However, it should collect field3 as crit3 for the second request.
                "from":         "collection",
                "localField":   "nested.nested.field3",
                "foreignField": "nested.nested.field3",
                "as":           "crit3",
            }}},
        bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{
            {"field", crit1},
            {"nested.nested.field3", "crit3"}, // crit3 should be used. Crit3 hardcoded is working
        }}},
        bson.D{{"$project", bson.M{
            "proj1":  "$someValue1",
            "proj2": "$someValue2",
        }}},
    })
```

Hardcoded "crit3" would work in second match statement.Is it possible to handle the action in one request?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match all the documents, where two different fields match each other? If yes you can try this one:

```
    bson.D{{"$addFields", bson.D{
        "myFieldMatch": {"$eq": ["$nested.nested.field3", "$nested.nested.field4"]} 
    }}},
    bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{
        "myFieldMatch": true 
    }}}
```

You do not need a lookup stage if you want to use fields within the same collection.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's a very exciting approach. In my case, the first match statement should return the value to be filtered by in the second match statement. Sorry I wrote it so vaguely.